# Criação de componente gerando DLL

Tags: vb.net, componentes

Modifiquei alguns componentes gerando uma DLL ao compilar o projeto.
Existe alguma maneira dessa DLL só poder ser usada junto com o projeto atual?
Existe alguma maneira de não gerar a DLL e compilar tudo como um único executavel?

Comment: Adicione um exemplo mínimo de código para que seja possível identificar em que ponto do desenvolvimento o problema se encontra. Vai permitir uma análise mais precisa e do problema e consequentemente uma melhor solução, sem suposições.

Answer (score 0):

> Existe alguma maneira dessa DLL só poder ser usada junto com o projeto
>   atual?

Existe um negocio chamdado Strong Name, basicamente, ele vai criar um hash entre para a DLL, desse jeito o seu projeto fica amarrado a essa DLL:

Link:

[Strong-Named Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wd40t7ad(v=vs.110).aspx)
[How to: Sign an Assembly with a Strong Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/xc31ft41(v=vs.85))

> Existe alguma maneira de não gerar a DLL e compilar tudo como um único
>   executavel?

Existe um tipo de projeto chamada Shared, ele não gera DLL todo o código é colocado dentro do exe,  está disponível na versão do VS2015:

Link:
[Shared Project : An Impressive Feature of Visual Studio 2015 Preview](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/shared-project-an-impressive-features-of-visual-studio-201/)

[Visual Basic 14 - Novidades da Nova Versão - Shared Projects](http://www.macoratti.net/15/09/vb14_nov145.htm)

[What is the difference between a Shared Project and a Class Library in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634753/what-is-the-difference-between-a-shared-project-and-a-class-library-in-visual-st)

Answer (score 0):

Espero que quando você esteja se referindo a componentes como sendo os controles utilizados para manipulação da interface com o usuário (i.e. textbox, combobox, etc.).

> Existe alguma maneira de não gerar a DLL e compilar tudo como um único executavel?

Sim, é possível possível estender componentes e fazer com que tudo seja compilado em um único executável. Para que isso ocorra basta criar a classe que estende o componente, ou seu próprio componente, dentro do projeto principal.

Repare que não se trata de incluir um projeto dentro do outro. O código referente ao componente deve ser *transportado* e adaptado dentro do projeto principal para que seja compilado no mesmo executável. Para qualquer outro projeto existente (fora do projeto principal) será criada uma DLL.

No exemplo a seguir, personalizei uma textbox e inseri uma propriedade chamada *CorFundo* (eu sei que já existe a BackColor, mas usei só como exemplo). Note que tudo está dentro do projeto principal.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public partial class TextBoxPersonalizada : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{

    public void CorFundo(System.Drawing.Color cor)
    {
        this.BackColor = cor;
    }

}
```

A personalização consiste em exibir a textbox com o fundo na cor vermelha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A imagem acima mostra o componente na ToolBox e adicionado ao formulário principal.

O código do formulário principal é:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxPersonalizada1.CorFundo(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    }
}
```

E o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Existe alguma maneira dessa DLL só poder ser usada junto com o projeto atual?

Quanto a utilização da DLL somente pelo projeto atual parece, a primeira vista, como algo incoerente. Se não desejas utilizar as funções dessa DLL com outros projetos, coloque estas funções dentro do projeto principal, pois justamente o propósito de utilizar bibliotecas é disponibilizar o acesso a métodos que possam ser compartilhados por vários aplicativos, evitando assim a duplicidade de código.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno.
No meu projeto dei uma incrementada no Textbox para ficar compativel às minhas necessidades e anexei no meu projeto.
No projeto agora tenho 2 projetos... um com o conjunto dos forms e o outro projeto com esse componente.
acontece que quando mando compilar ("build") ele cria o EXE dos forms e a DLL do componente.

Comment: Como expliquei acima, você precisa implementar essa TextBox "incrementada" dentro do projeto principal para poder criar um único executável. Se existir outro projeto além do principal, serão criadas DLLs.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer como vc disse... mas eu só consigo incluir um projeto existente dentro do Solution... e não dentro do projeto.

Dentro do meu Solution Explorer, aparecem 3 projetos... 1 de forms... e 2 outros de controles otimizados.
Só que quando compilo, ele cria 1 exe e 2 dll